# Ember.js service vs ember-redux

Tags: ember.js

We are evaluating tech stack for a customer portal project. While I have a (biased) secret love connection towards ember, I am almost convinced to use it for the project.

However, coming from a react.js background, I would like to ask about store (redux) and Ember services.

1. Are Ember services considered source of truth? Can they be used instead of ember-redux?
2. I have seen ember-redux addon. Seems good. However, whats the point if we have Ember.js services?
3. Any use-case when ember-redux can be preferred over Ember services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/applications/services/):

> A [Service](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/release/modules/@ember%2Fservice) is an Ember object that lives for the duration of the
>   application, and can be made available in different parts of your
>   application.

An Ember service doesn't provide any functionality out of the box. It's just an empty, long-lived object. You can put whatever you want in there: a shopping cart, a datastore, an activity feed, etc.

[Redux](https://redux.js.org/)—and by extension, ember-redux—is a pattern (and boilerplate) for implementing predictable state in your app. You can add states and reducers to any Ember object, including a service.

Comparing an Ember service and ember-redux is a bit like comparing a garage to a blueprint for building cars. You shouldn't be trying to decide whether to use one or the other. Instead, you should consider whether use that particular blueprint to build your cars, and then whether to store those cars in the garage or somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you. I think redux store is also an empty, long-lived object until it initialised. So, unable to understand use-case and when to use.

Comment: Sure, the Redux store provided by ember-redux happens to be an Ember service. If you want to use the Redux pattern, you need a store. If you don't want want to use the Redux pattern, you don't need a store. That really has no bearing on whether you decide to use services in your app or not.

Comment: Great, thanks!. Just last bit of explanation for a non-tech person. Services are essentially can be used for the same use-case as ember-redux. Is that statement correct? 
I am reluctant to use a community provided tool when we can do same thing with ember services. 

Anything I will miss if I don't use redux and just use ember services?

Comment: That statement is not correct. I recommend you watch a few "intro to Redux" [videos](https://redux.js.org/#just-the-basics) to help decide whether the Redux pattern makes sense for your app or not. If it does make sense, then you'll need to decide whether to use ember-redux or implement the Redux pattern yourself. Pro-Tip: You probably don't want to reinvent the wheel here.

Comment: Thank you. I wont reinvent but will look into it we really need redux in favor of services, particularly when we have services. I don't see one case which I can't do in service and able to do it in redux.

Comment: maybe its better to compare `ember-data` and `ember-redux`. While services are a more general pattern, its usually the way to implement any kind of long-living-state in ember. Redux can be one service, `ember-data` another, or a websocket connection, or authentication, or translations, just to list a few common examples.

Comment: @Lux thanks, so that means the state can be managed by ember services without using redux?

Comment: I m not sure how anyone can make this any clearer, redux is a pattern and also a buzzword that seems to affect people's judgment of what it is they need or don't, you can track state with ember-data, ember-redux, ember services, plain javascript objects and maybe even a potato if you daisy chain enough of them. What is the problem you are trying to solve that makes you think you require redux?

Comment: @PatsyIssa User authentication, a websocket connection to server and update state on data arrival and third requirement is to make data available everywhere in the application. I know that ember services can do everything above. So is redux. However, I am not a professional programmer and merely a student. I just need to grasp the concept of why would I choose redux vs service in that case.

Comment: @AlexRizvi Join us on the [ember community slack channel](https://emberjs.com/community/) it would be easier to have the conversation there ^^

Comment: Maybe a big problem for you to understand that you just listed multiple problems. Problably noone needs redux for anything (or ember), it just can make things easier. For now as a beginner I recommend you to maybe stick with `ember-data` and `ember-simple-auth`, while knowing redux is a powerful, but maybe for now too complicated tool for you. However if you *know* redux it might be easier for you to start with `ember-redux` and ignore `ember-data` for now. In the end its the question about your preferences. And yeah, join the slack channel!